# Random integer range with exceptions

Tags: c#, unity3d

I have to generate a random number from a range with exceptions held in a bool array, is there a way to do it without a loop depending on probability?
There is also a potential infinite loop here if all values are false.
Any suggestions?

```
    bool[] paths = InnateChannels(channelID, channelOrientation);

    bool done = false;
    int iDirection = 0;
    while (!done)
    {
        iDirection = Random.Range(0, 4);
        if (paths[iDirection])
            done = true;
    }
    direction = DirectionToVector(iDirection);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do. You want to generate how many random nubers?

Comment: one random number given a range with exceptions

Comment: What do you mean by _a range with exceptions_? Let's say the `paths` array contains these values: `{ true, true, false, true, false, false, true }`- how many random number do expect from it? Currently it's a totaly random result but apperently you don't want it like that so what would be the _correct_ result?

Comment: So paths[0],paths[1], paths[3],paths[6] are true, that means I want the method to generate a random number from 0,1,3,6. Sorry if I am unclear, I had to rush it since I was leaving for a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already noticed, your code will loop forever if all array elements
are `false`, so you have to check first if at least one element is true.

If the array has \$ N \$ elements with \$ t \$ of them being `true`, then
the probability that a random number in the range \$ 0 ... N-1 \$ is
"valid" is \$ t/N \$. This means that the expected number of iterations
is \$ N/t \$. For example, if half of the possible directions are valid,
you'll need 2 iterations in average. If only 1% are valid, you'll need
100 iterations in average.

Here is a possible alternative which needs only a single random number.
As I am not so familiar with C#, I'm
describing the algorithm only.

- Count the number \$ t \$ of `true` elements in the array.
  Terminate if \$ t = 0 \$.
- Compute a random number \$ i \$ in the range \$ 1 ... t \$.
- Traverse the array once to find the \$i^\text{th} \$ entry which is `true`.
  The index of that element is your result.

Comment: The back slashes and dollar signs make your text hard to read, thanks though.

Comment: @OmarChehab: You are welcome! – The backslashes and dollar signs make the text render as LaTeX formulas, see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex. Perhaps that does not work in your browser?

Answer (score 2):

You write in your [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110086/random-integer-range-with-exceptions/110088#comment202789_110086)

> So `paths[0]`, `paths[1]`, `paths[3]`, `paths[6]` are true, that means I want the method to generate a random number from 0,1,3,6. [...].

You can achieve this with `LINQ`:

```
// a few test values
var paths = new[] { true, true, false, true, false, false, true };

// initialize random numbers generator
var rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

// get a random number for each 'true' value
var randomNumber = paths.Where(p => p).Select(p => rnd.Next(0, 4)).ToArray();
```

---

Remember to use constants instead of magic numbers:

```
const int minNumber = 0;
const int maxNumber = 4;
```